# How to run a javascript github repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, repository

I found a repo I would like to use that does not include much instruction and is written in all javascript. I've installed the basic requirements, but I don't know how to proceed. 
This is the main repo https://github.com/website-scraper/website-scraper-puppeteer and it uses the plugin https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer to add extra functionality.

How do I run the code? It is unclear in the README.

Comment: The README file seems sufficiently clear. Perhaps you can make your question more specific?

Comment: How do I copy a website? That is not clear. Is it from the terminal? How do I run code that is all javascript? The README only includes code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the instructions for puppeteer. It explains it's a node module.

So you need to install node.js from the command line.

Then using node's npm to install puppeteer.

Then add the plugin.

And finally, run puppeteer

Please acquaint yourself with "what is a node.js application" first.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm

Answer (score 0):

To download website using website-scraper-puppeteer node module you need:

- install nodejs (version >= 8)
- install modules `website-scraper` (core module), `website-scraper-puppeteer` (plugin for core module) from npm

```
npm install website-scraper website-scraper-puppeteer
```

- create file for your nodejs application (for example, `index.js`) with some code

```
const scrape = require('website-scraper');
const PuppeteerPlugin = require('website-scraper-puppeteer');

const options = {
    urls: ['https://example.com'],
    directory: '/path/to/save',
    plugins: [ 
      new PuppeteerPlugin()
    ]
};

scrape(options).then((result) => { console.log(result); });
```

- run you app from command line

```
node index.js
```